# Delete header in django rest framework response

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, response-headers

I'm trying to delete `Server` header from django rest framework response, but I didn't find an easy way, so I create a middleware to delete it.

This is my first try:

**middleware.py**

```
class RemoveHeaders(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        response['Server'] = ''
        return response
```

This middleware works ok, but the problem is that it fills `server` header with empty string and not delete it. so I tried the next:

```
class RemoveHeaders(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        del response['Server']
        return response
```

But It doesn't work. `server` header continues.

How can I delete `server` header?, or do you know another alternative?
thanks

**Updated**, these are my middlewares, maybe someone is override `server` header, case it doesn't exist?

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'my_api.middleware.RemoveHeaders'
)
```

Comment: Why you want to remove this header?

Comment: @SHIVAMJINDAL, because it gives sensible information, for example: `Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.5.3`

Comment: This should be done in server config file imho. In example for nginx you should look for `proxy_set_header`

Answer (score 3):

I just had the exact same problem. Your approach with

```
del response['Server']
```

Is correct!

However, you need to move your middleware to be the first. As other middlewares will add headers after the response is constructed, so the order of application is bottom-up. Your middleware has to be the first one to have the "last word".