# Django - How to hide Server [HTTP Response header] parameter in middleware file?

Tags: python, django, server, middleware, django-middleware

In my Django application, the following settings ensure that the response headers have the standard key-value pairs enabled.

However, the **'Server' name and version information is still visible by default which needs to be hidden** (exposed server name and version is an OWASP vulnerability).

#### middleware.py

```
class MyAppMiddleware:

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        response['X-XSS-Protection'] = "1; mode=block"
        return response


class RemoveHeaders(object):           # this method invocation throws error
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        response['Server'] = ''
        return response
```

Also as suggested in other posts, this middleware.py is declared in the first order of middlewares in settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'MyApp.middleware.RemoveHeaders',
    'MyApp.middleware.MyAppMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

**The RemoveHeaders() method throws error: TypeError: RemoveHeaders() takes no arguments.** This is because I am unsure which object is being passed to this method.

**Update: importing the following worked for me.**

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin


# class to import in RemoveHeaders--

class RemoveHeaders(MiddlewareMixin):
     # rest of the code
```

Comment: Is this being followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50493701/delete-header-in-django-rest-framework-response?

Comment: Yes I did. The code snipped above has been updated. However the 'RemoveHeaders' method separately created for dealing with hiding response headers, throws an error on method invocation

Comment: In the `__call__`, I added this line `print('Response has Server header', response.has_header('Server'))` which printed `False`. This means that `Server` header is not even set at that point. I am not sure where is it set and why does second method work.

Answer (score 0):

@stackoverflowusrone   I find this from  django v3.7 source code, the server header is from here :
[image]

however i don't know how to del it

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using GUNICORN in production here is answer for you.**

1- Create a file gunicorn.config.py in same directory where settings.py file exist.

2- Write following code in gunicorn.conf.py file

```
import gunicorn
gunicorn.SERVER_SOFTWARE = "My Own Server"
```

3- update django app entrypoint

```
gunicorn --config python:MYAPP.gunicorn pelocal_rm_api.wsgi --bind 0.0.0.0
```

Please upvote if it's works for you.