# Delete 'Server' response header in Django framework - V3.0.5

Tags: python, django, security, http-headers

Before I begin my question, I have referred the stackoverflow post - [Delete header in django rest framework response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50493701/delete-header-in-django-rest-framework-response).

Please find the middleware code and settings.py below (referred to the [django middleware docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/middleware/)):

**middleware.py**:

```
class SimpleMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        response.__setitem__('Server', '')
        return response
```

**settings.py**

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ....,
    ....,
    'middleware_demo.middleware.SimpleMiddleware',
]
```

With the above code, I get the server response with the server header set to empty string as below. Which is as expected and doesn't disclose the server header details:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 21 Apr 2020 12:55:25 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Server: 
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Length: 16351
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

My goal is to remove the header altogether and tried 2 ways for the same in **middleware.py**:

**Method 1** - [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.__delitem__)

```
class SimpleMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        response.__delitem__('Server')
        return response
```

**Method 2** - referred stackoverflow blog - [Delete header in django rest framework response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50493701/delete-header-in-django-rest-framework-response)

```
class SimpleMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        del response['Server']
        return response
```

But the response still has the server header set and shows the version details too as below:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 21 Apr 2020 13:00:26 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.6.5
Content-Type: text/html
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Length: 16351
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

My question is why does the server header value get modified and comes up as empty string when modified, but when the header value itself is deleted, I'm seeing it in the response header.
What is it that I'm missing here ?

Also, I have tried moving the middleware activation line to the first position and the last position, just in case something is being overriden. Still the same issue.

Comment: Are you using Django `runserver`? In that case, I think the default header is being set by [wsgiref](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wsgiref.html) so you would have to look at that to see whether you can prevent the header from being set. In Production, you won't be using `runserver` anyway, so I wouldn't worry about getting rid of the Server header in Django. For example, if you deploy Django with Nginx/gunicorn, you would configure the Server header in the Nginx config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is right, except that you can't delete it or django will add it back.
You must either make it blank or modify it...

```
response.headers['Server'] = "None of your beeswax!"
```

[request header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGwaU.png)

Comment: I tried this solution and it worked fine. But, when I click on img/css/js file and see the response header. The original server name is still visible. Any suggestions?

Comment: The header may be added by the server itself and not django.  I'd check the server config.